# How to loop test run on Android J Unit Test?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit, robotium

I have created a test for my application on Eclipse. I am using Robotium 5.0.1. The test I am carrying out is...Start MainActivity.class > click on menuitem (addperson) > this automatically takes it to the add screen and the edit texts are filled and "save" is pressed and the app then closes; test passed without fail.

What I want to do is run the test multiple times without having to re-run the test, e.g test the app for adding 100 people.

this is my test class:

```
package com.androidbegin.databasetutorial.test;

import com.androidbegin.databasetutorial.MainActivity;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;
import com.androidbegin.databasetutorial.R;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class InitialButtonTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

private Solo solo;
public InitialButtonTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);

}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //setUp() is run before a test case is started. 
    //This is where the solo object is created.
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

public void testAddRemove() throws Exception
{
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Check on first activity", MainActivity.class);
    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.action_addperson);
    solo.enterText(0, "id number");
    solo.enterText(1, "Name");
    solo.enterText(2, "Last Name");
    solo.enterText(3, "Address");
            solo.enterText(4, "Contact number");
            solo.enterText(5, "Code");
            solo.enterText(6, "Date");
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("Save Note");


}
}
```

Can you please help me or guide me to a loop code that i can implement into this code.

Few requirments (although not essential): 
solo.enterText(0) << if it is possible to add a random number at most 7 digits long.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in a for cycle

```
public void testAddRemove() throws Exception
{
    //it runs it 1000 times
    addRemove(1000);
}

public void addRemove(int NUMBER_OF_TIMES) throws Exception
{
for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_TIMES; i++){
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Check on first activity", MainActivity.class);
    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.action_addperson);
    solo.enterText(0, "id number");
    solo.enterText(1, "Name");
    solo.enterText(2, "Last Name");
    solo.enterText(3, "Address");
    solo.enterText(4, "Contact number");
    solo.enterText(5, "Code");
    solo.enterText(6, "Date");
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("Save Note");
}
}
```